# Change text after load in windows application c#

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to change text on another form load but it wont works.
below is my form home page

```
  public partial class Home : Form
    {
    private Login frmlogin = new Login();
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      ComponentResourceManager componentResourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof (Home));


      this.documentSpace1.TabIndex = 4;
      this.documentSpace1.LogoutEvent += new DocumentSpace.logoutDelegate(this.documentSpace1_LogoutEvent);
      this.documentSpace1.MyTextEvent_SelectedObject += new DocumentSpace.MyDelegate(this.documentSpace_SelectedObjectEvent);
      this.documentSpace1.SetFormCaption += new DocumentSpace.MyDelegate(this.documentSpace1_SetFormCaption);
      this.documentSpace1.MyTextEvent_temp += new DocumentSpace.MyDelegate(this.documentSpace_TextEvent);
      this.documentSpace1.ShowHideStatusbar += new DocumentSpace.StatusBar(this.documentSpace_StatusbarEvent);
      this.documentSpace1.DispalyModeName += new DocumentSpace.MyDelegate(this.documentSpace1_DispalyModeName);
      this.panel1.Controls.Add((Control) this.documentSpace1);

      this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Home_Load);
        this.Activated+=new EventHandler(Home_Activated);


    }
  }
```

here i tried to change toolstrip item name , it change but after load while check it change to default.(i.e change according to next form intialize component)

```
 private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Show();
      this.Activate();
      this.SetFormName();

      if (about.Text == "About")
      {
          ((Button)about.Controls["button1"]).Text = "test_Button";
          ((Label)about.Controls["label3"]).Text = "test";
      }


    }
```

I tried same in form activated also but no use.

```
 private void Home_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("apProposToolStripMenuItem") { Name = "About" };
        mi.Enabled = false;
        mi.Visible = false;
        if (about.Text == "About")
        {
            ((Button)about.Controls["button1"]).Text = "test_Button";
            ((Label)about.Controls["label3"]).Text = "test";
        }
    }
```

Dll File :
in this dll file toolstrip item like this only.

```
this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Name = "apProposToolStripMenuItem";
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(122, 22);
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Text = "About";
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.apProposToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

help me to sort out this.

Comment: 'Another form load' ? what does this mean? Are you loading another form and hoping to change the first form when this happens? It isn't very clear what you are trying to acheive. Also what is this 'about' variable. What type is it, where is it declared?

Comment: i tried to from form1 load function to form 2 .About is toolstripmenu item

Answer (score 1):

try changing the sequence as below:

```
private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (about.Text == "About")
  {
      ((Button)about.Controls["button1"]).Text = "test_Button";
      ((Label)about.Controls["label3"]).Text = "test";
  }

  this.Show();
  this.Activate();
  this.SetFormName();
}
```